# Collecting amavis stats with SNMP

Tags: monitoring, snmp, amavis

I'm trying to get values from amavis in a CentOS 6.5 server.

This values, such as spam mail (total, total/h, percent), are supposed to be accesible via SNMP.

But, when I run snmpwal, I always get 0 as value (example):

```
AMAVIS-MIB::inMsgsInbound.0 = Counter32: 0
AMAVIS-MIB::sysUpTime.0 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
```

For this, I set up snmpd in my server. Here is my snmpd.conf

```
rocommunity snmp@key 192.168.1.12
rocommunity snmp@key 127.0.0.1


#       sec.name  source          community
com2sec notConfigUser  default       public

#       groupName      securityModel securityName
#group   notConfigGroup v1           notConfigUser
group   notConfigGroup v2c           notConfigUser

#       name           incl/excl     subtree         mask(optional)
view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.1
view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.4.1.15312.2.1
#       group          context sec.model sec.level prefix read   write  notif
access  notConfigGroup ""      any       noauth    exact  systemview none none
access  notConfigGroup ""      any       noauth    exact  agentx none none

syslocation Unknown (edit /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf)
syscontact Root <root@localhost> (configure /etc/snmp/snmp.local.conf)

dontLogTCPWrappersConnects yes

master agentx
agentXSocket tcp:127.0.0.1:705
```

I also set up amavis agentx by installing `amavisd-new-snmp` package and copying `AMAVIS-MIB.txt` in `/usr/share/snmp/mibs/`

All processess are up
I googled for a while, but I didn't get any info
Any idea will be appreciated